# How do I get an object from this tree in mongoDb?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

How do I get an object from this tree? :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("33b97aa654bce61322002559"),
    "name" : "Test",
    "children" : [
        "_id" : ObjectId("44b97aa654bce61322002559"),
        "name" : "Test Children",
        "children" : [
            "_id" : ObjectId("55b97aa654bce61322002559"),
            "name" : "Test Children Children",
            "children" : "",
            "products" : [
                "_id" : ObjectId("55b97aa654bce61322002559"),
                "name" : "Product 1" //I need this object
                "attrib" : [
                    "sale" : 1,
                    "new" : 1,
                    "instock" : 1,
                ]
            ],
            "products" : ""
        ]
    ],
    "products" : ""
}
```

Levels can be any number.

- children
- -children
- --children
- ---children
- ----children

  $arr = Categories::findOne(['_id' => '55b97aa654bce61322002559']);
  debug($arr);

Maybe I'm not shaping the structure db correctly?
Thank you.

Comment: This is JSON right?

Comment: Yes this is JSON

Comment: This looks like a MongoDB output?  Looking at the data, I think SQL might be a better fit.  If that isn't possible, you might consider making 2 collections: 1 that just stores products, and another that stores this hierarchy as nested `_id`s.

Comment: But is not mongodb designed to store such data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//return an array of objects according to key, value, or key and value matching
function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else
        //if key matches and value matches or if key matches and value is not passed (eliminating the case where key matches but passed value does not)
        if (i == key && obj[i] == val || i == key && val == '') { //
            objects.push(obj);
        } else if (obj[i] == val && key == ''){
            //only add if the object is not already in the array
            if (objects.lastIndexOf(obj) == -1){
                objects.push(obj);
            }
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```